# How do I check if a value exists and print that value if it does from a dictionary that is inside of a list?

Tags: python

I am attempting to find the value of a particular key from within a dictionary that is itself within a list, and then print that value.

```
iso3166_1 = [
  {
    "name_en": "Afghanistan",
    "name_fr": "Afghanistan (l')",
    "full_name": "the Islamic Republic of Afghanistan",
    "alpha2": "AF",
    "alpha3": "AFG",
    "numeric": "004",
    "independent": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "name_en": "Åland Islands",
    "name_fr": "Åland(les Îles)",
    "full_name": "N/A",
    "alpha2": "AX",
    "alpha3": "ALA",
    "numeric": "248",
    "independent": "No"
  },
  {
    "name_en": "Albania",
    "name_fr": "Albanie (l')",
    "full_name": "the Republic of Albania",
    "alpha2": "AL",
    "alpha3": "ALB",
    "numeric": "008",
    "independent": "Yes"
  }
]

print("Are you looking for an existing country, subdivision, or former country? Type 1, 2, or 3 for that option.")
user_input = input()

if user_input == "1":
  print("Enter the name or code of a country.")
  lookup = str.lower(input())
  if lookup == "N/A":
    print("'N/A' is present in too many entries to list.")
  else:
    for entry in iso3166_1:
      for i in entry:
        if lookup == i:
          found_lookup = True
          dict = iso3166_1.index(entry)
          name_en = iso3166_1[iso3166_1.index(entry)]["name_en"]
          print(f"Short-form English name: {name_en}")
        else:
          print("Not found.")
```

The problem is that it fails to find the dictionary and prints `Not found.` regardless of what is inputted by the user.

The aforementioned problem is everything under the for loop starting at `for entry in iso3166_1:`, but a small section of the list of dictionaries is included for context.

Comment: What exactly is "the problem"?

Comment: `for i in entry:` is looping through keys, not values. Perhaps you want `for key, value in entry.items():`?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you familiarise yourself with this part of the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) Also, when you ask "check if a value exists", do you really mean that or do you mean check if a **key** exists?

Comment: Note: using [`casefold()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=casefold#str.casefold) is probably better than using `lower()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner loop, try looping over the values in the `entry` dictionary, e.g.,

```
if user_input == "1":
  print("Enter the name or code of a country.")
  found_lookup = False
  lookup = str.lower(input())
  if lookup == "N/A":
    print("'N/A' is present in too many entries to list.")
  else:
    for entry in iso3166_1:
      # loop over values in entry dictionary
      for i in entry.values():
        # compare values to the input
        if lookup == i.lower():
          found_lookup = True
          # get the short form English name from entry
          name_en = entry["name_en"]
          print(f"Short-form English name: {name_en}")
          break
      else:
        # break out the loop
        if found_lookup:
          break
    if not found_lookup:
      print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 1):

The core part of your code can be greatly simplified as follows:

```
query = input("Enter the name or code of a country: ").lower()

def get_values(dlist):
    for d in dlist:
        yield d, map(str.lower, d.values())

for d, v in get_values(iso3166_1):
    if query in v:
        print(d["name_en"])
        break
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that creating the `set` object is worth it for just one check. May as well just yield the iterable result of `map()`

Answer (score 0):

```
query = input("Enter the name or code of a country: ").lower()

name = next(
  (
    d['name_en']
      for d in iso3166_1
        if query in map(str.lower, d.values())
  ), 
  None
)

print()

if name is not None:
  print('Found:', name)
else:
  print('No match found.')
```

Demo : https://ideone.com/1WwXMD

Or, simpler but not necessarily as fast...

```
name = next(
  (
    d['name_en']
      for d in iso3166_1
      for s in d.values()
        if query == str.lower(s)
  ),
  None
)
```

In both cases the loop is done inside a comprehension, which returns a generator object.  Passing that to `next()` "runs the loop" until the first result is yielded (returning None if no result is found).